# CSS3 Underlying Image can't Hoverover In I.E. It work in Firefox using Pointer Event

Tags: jquery, css

I Have one big image inside i have small 13 image. I want to hoverover inside image but below code work in Firefox but it doesn't work in I.E 8 and 9.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <script type='text/javascript' src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $(".box").hover(function() {
            $(this).removeClass("box").addClass("boxhover");
                }, function() {
            $(this).removeClass("boxhover").addClass("box");
        });


    });
</script> 
<body>
    <style type="text/css">
        .outside { width: 1000px; height: 771px; position:absolute; z-index:9; background-image:url(eye.png); 
        <!-- pointer-events: none; -->
        ms-filter: 'filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src=eye.png, sizingMethod=scale)'; } .outsidelowindex { width: 1000px; height: 771px; position:absolute; z-index:-1; background-image:url(eye.png); 
        <!-- pointer-events: none; -->
        ms-filter: 'filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src=eye.png, sizingMethod=scale)'; } .imagesbox { width:577px; height:575px; padding-top: 92px; padding-left:211px; z-index:1; } .imagea { background-color: #fff; width:58px; height:115px; float:left; } .imageb { background-color: #fff; width:53px; height:115px; float:left; } .imagec { background-color: #fff; width:55px; height:116px; float:left; } .imaged { background-color: #fff; width:53px; height:116px; float:left; } .image1 { width:278px; height:115px; float:left; position:relative; overflow:hidden; } .image2 { width:188px; height:115px; float:left; overflow:hidden; } .image3 { width:204px; height:113px; float:left; overflow:hidden; } .image4 { width:180px; height:113px; float:left; overflow:hidden; } .image5 { width:193px; height:113px; float:left; overflow:hidden; } .image6 { width:158px; height:116px; float:left; overflow:hidden; } .image7 { width:254px; height:116px; float:left; overflow:hidden; } .image8 { width:165px; height:116px; float:left; overflow:hidden; } .image9 { width:214px; height:115px; float:left; overflow:hidden; } .image10 { width:231px; height:115px; float:left; overflow:hidden; } .image11 { width:132px; height:115px; float:left; overflow:hidden; } .image12 { width:221px; height:116px; float:left; overflow:hidden; } .image13 { width:248px; height:116px; float:left; overflow:hidden; } .box { z-index: 5; transform: scale(1); -moz-transform: scale(1); -webkit-transform: scale(1); transition: background-color 1s, box-shadow 1s, transform 0.5s; -moz-transition: background-color 1s, -moz-box-shadow 1s, -moz-transform 0.5s; -webkit-transition: background-color 1s, -webkit-box-shadow 1s, -webkit-transform 0.5s; } .boxhover { z-index: 10; box-shadow: 0 0 15px #000; -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 15px #000; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 15px #000; transform: scale(1.1); -moz-transform: scale(1.1); -webkit-transform: scale(1.1); } 
    </style>
    <div class="outside"></div>
    <div class="imagesbox">
        <div class="imagea"></div>
        <div class="image1 box">
            <a href="#"><img
                    src="" alt="Impact
                    2018" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="image2 box">
            <a href="#"><img
                    src="" alt="Impact
                    2018" /></a>
        </div>
        <!--   <div class="imageb"></div> -->
        <div class="image3 box">
            <a href="#"><img
                    src="" alt="Impact
                    2018" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="image4 box">
            <a href="#"><img
                    src="" alt="Impact
                    2018" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="image5 box">
            <a href="#"><img
                    src="" alt="Impact
                    2018" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="image6 box">
            <a href="#"><img
                    src="" alt="Impact
                    2018" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="image7"></div>
        <div class="image8 box">
            <a href="#"><img
                    src="" alt="Impact
                    2018" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="image9 box">
            <a href="#"><img
                    src="" alt="Impact
                    2018" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="image10 box">
            <a href="#"><img
                    src="" alt="Impact
                    2018" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="image11 box">
            <a href="#"><img
                    src="" alt="Impact
                    2018" /></a>
        </div>
        <!--  <div class="imagec"></div> -->
        <div class="image12 box">
            <a href="#"><img
                    src="" alt="Impact
                    2018" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="image13 box">
            <a href=""><img
                    src="" alt="Impact
                    2018" /></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `.outside` element is positioned over the images. Anybody who tries to hover over the images is actually hovering over the `.outside` element. IE 10 and below does not support `pointer-events` either. `Pointer-events` would fix your problem, but they are [*currently* not widely supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events).

I may be able to help you find a work around, but you need to explain what you're trying to accomplish.